# How to make a custom method that takes an arbitrary Flex component as an argument?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, user-interface

I'm trying to write a custom `fadeTo(component, x, y):void` method, which takes an arbitrary Flex Component as an argument and moves it to a given location, but smoothly.

**The problem I'm running into is the following.**

I want to send the component itself as argument, like this: (using Button as an example only)

`fadeTo(myButton, 200, 500);`

(this should move `myButton` smoothly from its current position to the position indicated as parameter)

**However**, I don't really know what **type** an arbitrary Flex Component **is**. **How should I handle that?**

What I would like is some advice as to how to proceed.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [UIComponent](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/UIComponent.html) as the argument type:

```
public function fadeTo(component:UIComponent, x:int, y:int):void{
 // do stuff
}
```

Or possibly [IUIComponent](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/IUIComponent.html):

```
public function fadeTo(component:IUIComponent, x:int, y:int):void{
 // do stuff
}
```

If you want to be truly generic, you can use the type Object:

```
public function fadeTo(component:Object, x:int, y:int):void{
  if(component is IUIComponent){
    // do stuff
  }
}
```

Comment: `component == IUIComponent` will not evaluate to true because the component instance can never equal the Interface itself. Generally speaking, passing the parameter as an object isn't a good idea, but if you did, cast it within a `try/catch`, or do a `typeof` comparison.

Comment: Hmm.. I'll try that and come back to mark it as the right answer. By the way, I think I've come across this flextras.com website before and downloaded some stuff.

Comment: @Slomojo I should have used "is" instead of '=='.  My typo.  I think doing a compare is a lot more elegant than casting it w/ a try/catch.  Is that why this answer got downvoted?

Comment: @Felipe Almeida Thanks for checking out our components. :-)  We're an e-mail away if we can help.

Comment: I would use IVisialElement instead.... However, the framework usually just passes an Object for an effect target.

Comment: @drkstr IVisualElement seems like a valid choice.  It really depends what you're trying to do.